# How do I get this random number generator out of an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I have an assignment for school where I need to create a lottery program. It is supposed to allow the user to input six numbers and then generate six random numbers for comparison. I got the inputs working, but I have encountered a problem where the random number generator (located in the while loop) is stuck in an infinite loop, and I have absolutely no idea what is causing it since I have never had an infinite loop in any previous programs. If someone could please look through the code and possibly establish what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

void randomizeSeed();
int randomRange(int min, int max);
int getInteger();

int main()
{
randomizeSeed();

const int minNumber = 1;
const int maxNumber = 49;
const int Size = 6;
int luckyNumbers[6] = {};
int randomNumber = randomRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
int winningNumbers[6] = {};

cout << "Enter six numbers between 1 and 49...\n";
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        luckyNumbers[i] = getInteger();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Size - 1; i++)
        {
            if (luckyNumbers[i] > luckyNumbers[i + 1])
            {
                int temp = luckyNumbers[i];
                luckyNumbers[i] = luckyNumbers[i + 1];
                luckyNumbers[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Lucky Numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        cout << luckyNumbers[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Press any button to see the Winning Numbers.\n";
    system("pause");

    bool exist = true;
    while (exist == true)
    {
        int count = 0;
        cout << "Winning Numbers: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            winningNumbers[j] = randomRange(1, 49);
            cout << winningNumbers[j] << " ";
            system("pause");
        }
    }
}
}

void randomizeSeed()
{
srand(time(NULL));
}

int randomRange(int min, int max)
{
int randomValue = rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min;
return randomValue;
}

int getInteger()
{
int value = 0;
while (!(cin >> value) || (value >= 50) || (value <= 0))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
return value;
}
```

Comment: "If someone could please look through the code" - that someone is YOU! Use your debugger.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: So, where do you set `exist` to false to end the loop?

Comment: My debugger wasn't showing that anything was wrong. I finally got the program working. Thank you for the helpful hint.

Comment: Now that I've figured that out, would someone be able to tell me why the random number generator generates one number followed by zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < Size - 1; i++)
        if (luckyNumbers[i] > luckyNumbers[i + 1])
        {
            int temp = luckyNumbers[i];
            luckyNumbers[i] = luckyNumbers[i + 1];
            luckyNumbers[i + 1] = temp;
        }
```

You have two loops and they both use `i`. You probably mean to use the second loop with another variable name, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < Size - 1; k++)
    {
        if (luckyNumbers[i] > luckyNumbers[k + 1])
        {
            int temp = luckyNumbers[i];
            luckyNumbers[i] = luckyNumbers[k + 1];
            luckyNumbers[k + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you set your compiler warning level to 4 then compiler should warn you about these errors. Try to resolve all compiler warnings.